# SSH connections blocked for connected VPN clients when UFW is enabled

Tags: ssh, openvpn, ubuntu-14.04

We have an Ubuntu server running an OpenVPN server that clients connects to.

The problem is that if we enable UFW on this sever, allowing incoming VPN connections, VPN clients cant SSH computers in the servers subnet. They can ping them, but not connect via SSH.

If we disable UFW it works just fine.

What we have tried:
Adding the OpenVPN subnet to the allow list of UFW - does not work
Adding the local subnet to the allow list of UFW - does not work

Anyone have a suggestion?

UFW Status:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
1194                       ALLOW       Anywhere
1194 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Can you enable UFW and paste the result of ufw status as an edit to the question?

Comment: @eranga, sure, done.